# Creating API service to load processed data with html on an external website (require logic)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, websocket, webhooks

Need to figure out how chat providers like tawk.to or zopim works.
These site give you a small js code like this:

```
    var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
        Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
(function() {
    var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
        s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s1.async = true;
    s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/5b1a548e10b99c7b36d4bf04/default';
    s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
})();
```

And you are supposed to place the code on your website and the chat is loaded.

Suppose I have created a chatbot where when you send `Hi` it sends back `Hello`

And, I have created a Restful API like this:
`domain.com/query?token=11223344&message=hi`

I can definitely execute the URL with an ajax call on any of my page.
BUT, how can I create an Service API for this?

Best case scenario is where I provide a small js code with a token to anyone and they place the code on their website and the html is parsed.

It should also be able to perform the example functionality (say `Hi` get `Hello`)
Is there any framework which helps to achieve this functionality out of the box?

Note: Currently using Laravel as the Backend.

Comment: Actually Laravel have socket Broadcast to handle your issue, look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting.

Comment: Is it only possible with web sockets?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this? I am working on a similar requirement.